# Obtaining the coordinates of streamlines in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to perform a numerical computation of a plasma in the presence of a magnetic field(produced by a permanent magnet). I plotted the magnetic field from the data using the streamplot command:
[image: Field Plot]

Now, I want to manually create a mesh along the field lines for which I need the coordinates of points which are used to plot them. This is important to me because the plasma will either flow along or across the field line and I expect the code development to become easier.

I tried to analyze the output of the streamplot command but could not get the co-ordinates.

```
stream = ax.streamplot(Z, R, B_Z, B_R, color=color, linewidth=1,
         cmap=plt.cm.inferno,density=2.5, arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=1)
```

I understand that I could find the streamfunction by numerically integrating the field data and then use it to plot and store the coordinates of the streamlines but that will be cumbersome.

Please guide me towards any easier alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stream line segments by calling `.get_paths()` or `.get_segments()`.

```
stream = ax.streamplot(...)
paths = strm.lines.get_paths()
segments = strm.lines.get_segments()
```

However, those are the single segments of the lines and it is in general not clear which segment belongs to which line seen on the screen.

Since you seem to need the data for quantitative analysis, I would recommend not to rely on the streamplot itself (which is designed to give a good visual representation) but calculate the quantities from your data.

Answer (score 0):

Following on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I was able to achieve this goal through

```
density = 100 # defaults to 30- increased for more precision in the streamline
starting_point = np.array([[-180, -1980]])

strm = plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=density, start_points=starting_point)
num_pts = len(strm.lines.get_segments())
flow_line = np.full((num_pts, 2), np.nan)
for i in range(num_pts):
    flow_line[i,:] = strm.lines.get_segments()[i][0,:]
```